# How do I find USB connected removable hard drives in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to find all USB hard drives/SSD connected to my system.

The command
   **DriveGet, , Type**
should return these values
  "**Unknown, Removable, Fixed, Network, CDROM, RAMDisk.**"

The script below returns "**Fixed**" for every drive, no matter how it is connected.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
DriveGet, DriveList , List,
Loop,

{

  MyDrive :=  SubStr(Drivelist, A_Index,1)  

  If (MyDrive = "")
    break

  MyDrive = %MyDrive%

  DriveGet, MyLabel, serial, %MyDrive%
  DriveGet, MyType, Type,  %MyDrive%:\
  msgbox, Drive %MyDrive% Type %MyType%

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit on removable drives that the OS reads, and decides if they're removable or not (7th bit of the first byte).

The most likely case is that the drive isn't set as removable, so their isn't a solution unless you rewrite the bit.  Rewriting the bit isn't usually possible as it's on the controller, rather than the flash storage space.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why AHK reporta the drives as fixed even if the are not. Rewriting the bit will not work, because the whole point of the script is to find out if a drive is removable when the status is unknown. So maybe someone else has an idea on how do find out if a certain drive if connected via USB.

Comment: I think you can assume that the first 'fixed' drive after C: is removable; unless the hard drive is partitioned.

Comment: Currently on my system the drives C, E, F are fixed (two partitioned harddiscs) but this can change if I remove the second drive. So really I'm looking for a way to find out if a drive is USB connected or not without giving this information to the system manually. (which would be cheating...)

Answer (score 1):

It seems this was an issue that was resolved on the Autohotkey Forums using a script in [this post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/82826-solved-check-if-drive-is-an-external-hard-disk/?p=527171).  I've include the script from the thread below.  Give that a try.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
SetBatchLines -1
ListLines Off
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%


    pd := PhysicalFromLogical("F")       ; This is the drive you want to test
    if GetType(pd) = "Fixed" and GetInterface(pd) = "USB"
        MsgBox Drive is Fixed and USB
    else
        MsgBox Drive is either not Fixed or not USB
return


; Given a drive letter like "f" return the physical
; drive associated with it, i.e. \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2
PhysicalFromLogical(d)
{
    wmi := ComObjGet("winmgmts:")

    for LogicalDisk in wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")
        if InStr(LogicalDisk.Dependent,d)
            for Partition in wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")
                if (Partition.Dependent = LogicalDisk.Antecedent) {
                    Start := InStr(Partition.Antecedent, """") + 1
                    return SubStr(Partition.Antecedent, Start, -1)
                }
    return 0
}

; Given a drive path like \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2 return the
; drives interface type, i.e. "USB"
GetInterface(pd)
{
    wmi := ComObjGet("winmgmts:")

    for Drive in wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive where DeviceId = """ pd """")
        return Drive.InterfaceType
    return 0
}

; Given a drive path like \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2 return the drive type, i.e. "Removable"
; This is just a wrapper for DriveGet
GetType(pd)
{
    StringReplace pd, pd, \\, \, All
    DriveGet out, Type, %pd%
    return out 
}
```